# How to make Tampermonkey work on Google `chrome://` pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I want to make a script for Google pages like: `chrome://apps/`

But seems that Tampermonkey doesn't work on these pages. What should I do for the following script?

What I'm trying:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Some Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0
// @description  Trying to work in Google pages
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var myVar = 0;

if(window.location.href === "chrome://apps/"){ //check the URL
    if(myVar === 0){
        myVar++;
    alert("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Extensions (and therefore Tampermonkey) aren't able to run on any pages that start with `chrome`.

> Host permissions and content script matching are based on a set of URLs defined by match patterns. A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (`http`, `https`, `file`, or `ftp`, and that can contain `'*'` characters.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Chrome would not be a nice place if extensions/scripts could willfully mess with settings or install extensions.